# ValueError: Field 'maca' expected a number but got ''. Django error

Tags: python, django

I have a model like this

```
class Product(models.Model):

   class Maca(models.IntegerChoices):
       Yes = 1,
       No = 2,

   maca = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
       db_column='maca', choices=Maca.choices
   )
```

and a form like this

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
   maca = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=Product.Maca.choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

I have one case that this field will not show on the form.

But when it is not in the form, the field 'maca' will submitted as '' (Blankn) and I'm getting an error for this

```
ValueError: Field 'maca' expected a number but got ''.
```

Can someone help me please?
How can I send this in database as None value?

Answer (score 0):

A ModelForm field can be considered required or not required depending on the arguments of the fields in the model just as stated in the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types).

> If the model field has `blank=True`, then required is set to False on the form field. Otherwise, `required=True`.

I'd suggest you restructure your code this way.

**app/models.py**

```py
class Product(models.Model):

   class Maca(models.IntegerChoices):
       Yes = 1,
       No = 2,

   maca = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
       db_column='maca', choices=Maca.choices, blank=True, null=True
   )
```

**app/forms.py**

```py
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
   maca = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Product.Maca.choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

A ModelForm field is considered not required when it has `blank=True,`

`blank,` and  `null` arguments are `False` by default.